# WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING and main window visibility issue

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, mfc

I have a large C++/MFC application that can start in two modes: 1) regular GUI mode and 2) special mode when it was started with command line parameters in which case the GUI part of the program is not shown but instead I add an icon to the notification (system) tray.

To ensure that the main window is not shown for mode 2 I process the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING as follows:

```
void OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS* lpwndpos)
{
    CDialog::OnWindowPosChanging(lpwndpos);

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here

    //Prevent main window from showing
    lpwndpos->flags &= ~SWP_SHOWWINDOW;
}
```

The issue happens if after processing this message the logic determines an error in a command line and wants to show the main window. But I can't seem to show the main window after processing the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message like I showed above.

PS. The project is C++ MFC written for Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: If your OnWindowPosChanging handler is always clearing the `SWP_SHOWWINDOW` flag then your window will never be shown. Presumably you should have some sort of test to see if you actually do want to show the window or not before clearing the flag.

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way. If you don't want the window to show, stop showing it. It is in your gift whether or not to show the window. So I would get rid of `OnWindowPosChanging` altogether. If you want to show the window, show it. If you don't want to show the window don't show it. Trying to remedy matters, after the fact, by blocking a show in `OnWindowPosChanging` is not the way to approach this.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Your post actually answers my question. Thank you. I also learned experimentally that WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING is broadcast after WM_INITDIALOG, unless ShowWindow is called with in, which helps in its processing.